# Problem using \citep{} w/ biblatex and @online

Tags: biblatex

Got the following 
Document:

```
\documentclass[a4wide,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\bibliography{Bibliografie_AG.bib}

\begin{document}

Something blablabla \citep{MendeleySearch}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibliografie_AG.bib (e.g.):

```
@online{MendeleySearch,
 author               = {John Doe},
 month                = {5},
 title                = {Mendeley | Search},
 url                  = {http://www.mendeley.com/research-papers/},
 year                 = {2012},
 }
```

I'm using biblatex to reference URLs. But now I cannot use `/citep` or something listed [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib).

Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: The command `\citep` is provided by the `natbib` package. Do you maybe want to load the `biblatex` package with the `natbib=true` option to make it emulate the `\citep` command?

Comment: `\usepackage[natbib]{biblatex}` is now 'not giving errors' but, \citep{} doesn't give me the output between `(Author, Year)` as stated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by "the output between `(Author, Year)`". Are you looking to get a comma inserted between the author and year components? If so, be sure to set the instruction `\nameyeardelim{, }` somewhere in the preamble. (The default is a simple interword space.)

Comment: I'm referring to: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Natbib where is stated that `\citep{author93}` should give this `(Author, 1993)`

Comment: Have you tried the instruction `\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }` in the preamble of your document?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work. Just gives me `[1]` with the hyperlink to the bibliography, but not the `(Author, 1993)`-kind. However, `\citet{author93}` gives me `Author [1]`. But just `\citep{}` doesn't what it should do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following, simplified form of your MWE works fine if one remembers to run bibtex after the first LaTeX pass, and then run LaTeX twice more:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }

\bibliography{Bibliografie_AG.bib}

\begin{document}

Something blablabla \citep{MendeleySearch}, \ldots

As shown by \citet{MendeleySearch}, \ldots

\autocite{MendeleySearch} % same output as \citep

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in the comments, `\citep` is not a biblatex command. It is a `natbib` command. You can get biblatex to work with `\citep` by using the option `natbib=true`. However, you could also try biblatex's own command: `\parencite`.

For author year citations, you should also use one of the author year bibliography style options:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

See section 3.3 of the [biblatex manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for a list of styles. These include: `authoryear`, `authoryear-comp`, `authoryear-ibid` and `authoryear-icomp`.

Comment: Yes I know that as stated [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55248/problem-using-citep-w-biblatex-and-online/55254#comment115558_55248) but as I also explained, it doesn't work. Even `\parencite` does not work.

Comment: @Albert First "It doesn't work" doesn't help us: what appears where you expect the citation? Second, see my update. You need to tell biblatex that you want author (year) citations…

Comment: Thanks a lot. "it doesn't work" should be: It just gives me [1] with the hyperlink to the bibliography. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In place of `\citep{}` you should try it's `biblatex` equivalent: **`\parencite{}`**

Comment: @Downvoter: A reason would be nice. Maybe because `\parencite` is already part of Seamus' longer [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55254/16967).